# Add glyphicons to dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, imagebutton

I'm trying to add the glyphicon to a table that has rows dynamically created. My problem is adding the icon within my external js file.

```
function createRemoveRowButton(ArrayIndex) {
    var removeRowButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var image = document.createElement("input");
    image.src = "example.jpg";
    image.type = "image";
    removeRowButton.appendChild(image);
    removeRowButton.onclick = function() {
    deleteRow(ArrayIndex);
    };

    return removeRowButton;
}
```

I've looked on getbootstrap.com under the how to use section along with googling but so far no luck.

Comment: In Bootstrap 3, the Glyphicons aren't images, they're characters in a font. See http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use for usage with Bootstrap.

Comment: Just you had to append a span that has class 'glyphicon' and its font class like(glyphicon-remove) etc..